# Ajax Script won't load data-toggle dropdown

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

My ajax script doesn't load my bootstrap / data-toggle dropdown function, please help, thank you.

**my ajax:**

```
function load(parameter,id)
{
$.ajax({ type: "POST", url: 'php/ajax.php', data: parameter, 
        success: function(data) 
            {
            $('#'+id).html(data);
            },
        error: function()
            {
                alert('error');
            }
        });
};
```

**ajax.php:**

```
echo "<table class=\"table no-margin\" >
        <tr class=\"info\" >
            <td align=\"left\"><b> Filename </b></td>
            <td align=\"center\" width=\"55px\" style=\"vertical-align: middle;\" >00:00</td>
            <td align=\"right\"  width=\"55px\" style=\"vertical-align: middle;\">
                <div class=\"btn-group\">
                    <div data-toggle=\"dropdown\" class=\"btn btn-default btn-xs dropdown-toggle\">
                        <i class=\"fa fa-wrench\"></i>
                        <span class=\"caret\"></span>
                    </div>
                    <ul class=\"dropdown-menu pull-right\">
                        <li><a><i class=\"fa fa-user\"></i> User </a></li>
                        <li><a href=\"javascript:edit('this  is  a test');\" id=\"0\"><i class=\"fa fa-pencil-square-o\"></i> Edit</a></li>
                        <li><a href=\"#\"><i class=\"fa fa-download\"></i> Download</a></li>
                        <li><a href=\"#\"><i class=\"fa fa-trash-o\"></i> Delete</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>";
```

The dropdown doesn't work, this line:

```
<div data-toggle=\"dropdown\" class=\"btn btn-default btn-xs dropdown-toggle\">
```

Comment: A little part of me dies every time I see HTML created in a PHP file this way!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the Dom you create dynamically hasn't be parsed in `bootstrap` js. so may be you should declare like `$('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown()` after createing a new bootstrap plugin.

Comment: just try to write    $('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown();    after your     $('#'+id).html(data);    don't it works?

Comment: I just build a test use your code, it even works without `$('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown();`.  so can you make sure that your ajax has got your PHP response? just `console.log(data)` in success closure